# Solve the equation $ 10^n = 9 k^3 + 1 $ in natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve the equation $ 10^n = 9 k^3 + 1 $ in natural numbers
Of course $ n = 1 $ and $ k = 1 $ is a solution. Are there any other?

Alternatively:
Does exist any natural number composed of $ n $ ones in decimal system such that it is a perfect cube of natural number greater than 1?

Comment: This is already solved: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132011/can-repunits-be-perfect-cubes